# IDEA is using JRebel Debug, which is very confusing

Tags: intellij-idea, jrebel

The program collects data about 3-5s when it gets the parameter values
But using idea's own debug startup is fast

My IDEA version is 2020.1, and my JREBEL version is 2020.2.2

I searched for the cause of the problem, and someone said jdk version 1.8 localhost, and I tried to fix it, but that's not the problem I had

If you have any experience to help me, please feel free to say thank you

[image]

[image]

Comment: The slow debugger evaluation is a JRebel bug that's being looked at but will need help pinning down the cause. It will help us if you can collect stack traces from IntelliJ during the debugger evaluation or even better, attach a profiler and collect some metrics. IntelliJ has a CPU profiler built in that you can use: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241235-Reporting-performance-problems#CPU_Snapshot_2019_2 Start profiling, do some slow debugger evaluations, stop profiling and then send the CPU usage snapshot along with logs in .jrebel folder to support@jrebel.com

Comment: If I change to the earlier Jrebel version, can I use it normally?

Comment: The debugger integration has been improved since jrebel intellij plugin 2020.2.5. Does getting stuck on "Collecting data..." still happen on the latest versions?